# Adding a column to my dataframe based on other columns

Tags: r

I wish to add a new column to my dataframe called weekend which contains TRUE or FASLE if the day is in the weekend or not. This can be based off the date or weekday column. How would i do this?

data snipet

```
      Substation  Date       cluster  Time     Value  weekday
1     511016      2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6215941 Thursday
2     511029      2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5677445 Thursday
3     511030      2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6065458 Thursday
4     511033      2013-01-08       2 00:00 0.3090885  Tuesday
5     511034      2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5263230 Thursday
6     511035      2013-01-19       1 00:00 0.5267718 Saturday
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? where you replace `data` with your dataframe

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate(weekend = ifelse(weekday %in% c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"), F, T))
```

or

```r
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate(weekend = ifelse(weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), T, F))
```

Comment: Weirdly i get a 0.0000000 value in every row using both of these with T, F. Using the full word of TURE AND FALSE does however work correctly

Comment: just do `mutate(weekend = weekday %in% c('Saturday, 'Sunday'))` edit your code. No need of the `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

This can be informed by `?strptime` (which includes `%`-codes for `format(..)`):

```
     '%u' Weekday as a decimal number (1-7, Monday is 1).
```

Prep, in case you don't have `Date` objects in the `dat$Date` column:

```r
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)
```

Code:

```r
dat$is_weekend <- format(dat$Date, "%u") %in% 6:7
dat
#   Substation       Date cluster  Time     Value  weekday is_weekend
# 1     511016 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6215941 Thursday      FALSE
# 2     511029 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5677445 Thursday      FALSE
# 3     511030 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6065458 Thursday      FALSE
# 4     511033 2013-01-08       2 00:00 0.3090885  Tuesday      FALSE
# 5     511034 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5263230 Thursday      FALSE
# 6     511035 2013-01-19       1 00:00 0.5267718 Saturday       TRUE
```

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Substation = c(511016L, 511029L, 511030L, 511033L, 511034L, 511035L), Date = structure(c(15722, 15722, 15722, 15713, 15722, 15724), class = "Date"), cluster = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Time = c("00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00"), Value = c(0.6215941, 0.5677445, 0.6065458, 0.3090885, 0.526323, 0.5267718), weekday = c("Thursday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"), is_weekend = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c("1",  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `lubridate::wday`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(weekend = wday(ymd(Date)) %in% c(1,7))

#>   Substation       Date cluster  Time     Value  weekday weekend
#> 1     511016 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6215941 Thursday   FALSE
#> 2     511029 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5677445 Thursday   FALSE
#> 3     511030 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6065458 Thursday   FALSE
#> 4     511033 2013-01-08       2 00:00 0.3090885  Tuesday   FALSE
#> 5     511034 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5263230 Thursday   FALSE
#> 6     511035 2013-01-19       1 00:00 0.5267718 Saturday    TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution using `isWeekend` from  `timeDate`:

```
library(timeDate)

df$is_weekend <- isWeekend(as.Date(df$Date), wday = 1:5)
```

**Output**

```
  Substation       Date cluster  Time     Value  weekday is_weekend
1     511016 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6215941 Thursday      FALSE
2     511029 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5677445 Thursday      FALSE
3     511030 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.6065458 Thursday      FALSE
4     511033 2013-01-08       2 00:00 0.3090885  Tuesday      FALSE
5     511034 2013-01-17       1 00:00 0.5263230 Thursday      FALSE
6     511035 2013-01-19       1 00:00 0.5267718 Saturday       TRUE
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Substation = c(511016L, 511029L, 511030L, 511033L, 
511034L, 511035L), Date = c("2013-01-17", "2013-01-17", "2013-01-17", 
"2013-01-08", "2013-01-17", "2013-01-19"), cluster = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), Time = c("00:00", "00:00", "00:00", "00:00", 
"00:00", "00:00"), Value = c(0.6215941, 0.5677445, 0.6065458, 
0.3090885, 0.526323, 0.5267718), weekday = c("Thursday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"), is_weekend = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```